# How to force change password after first login

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Azure Active Directory B2C tenant. I also have a small service that creates new users in the B2C tenant from a different system. This way I can synchornize both systems. When a user has been added to B2C and logs in the first time, I want the user to be forced to change the password. But whatever I do, the user can just log in and continue, without changing the password..

To add a user to B2C, I use the Microsoft Graph 1.14 package. I push the user information as JSON to the endpoint https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users?api-version=1.6

The log in page is an Azure custom page in the user flow policies. There is also a change password policy, if needed.

This I tried:

- When adding the user, I set the password profile. Adding the property "ForceChangePasswordNextLogin" and setting it to true, does not work.
- Someone suggested to add the "ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn" property, but B2C doesn't know this property.
- Tried to fix it in the policy; didn't work.
- Used Google and StackOverflow; not much luck.

This is the user I post to Microsoft Graph:

```
var user = new GraphUserModel
{
    City = "Amsterdam",
    CustomField= "999999",
    Department = "TestPassword",
    DisplayName = "TestPassword",
    OtherMails = new[] { "myemail@something.nl" },
    PostalCode = "1234 AB",
    StreetAddress = "Hoofdweg 6",
    Surname = "TestPassword",
    TelephoneNumber = "0123456789",
    ChainCode = null,
    MailNickname = "999999",
    UserPrincipalName = "999999@{tenantNameHere}",
    SignInNames = new List<SignInNames>
    {
        new SignInNames
        {
            Type = "userName",
            Value = "999999"
        }
    },
    AccountEnabled = true,
    CreationType = "LocalAccount",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        Password = "SomeRandomPassword"
    },
    PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration"
};
```

The users are created correctly, but when they log in for the first time, I would like to see a page where they are forced to change the password.

Comment: Are you using sign-up/sign-in policy? Or you are using separately sign-in and sign-up?

Comment: @kgalic I am using the sign-in-sign-up policy, not separately.

Answer (score 3):

With Sign-up/Sign-in policy I had to implement that manually by flagging users in DB if they have changed the password and then redirecting to password change if they have not changed the password.

I was also not able to find 'out of the box' solution. I found that forceChangePasswordNextLogin works only with Sign-in policy.

Comment: `forceChangePasswordNextLogin works only with Sign-in policy`: [Here is the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions) supporting this claim. Also, the Azure AD team has [started planning](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861051-aadb2c-force-password-reset) to add this "force password reset" feature.